# How to pass an IFRAME SESSION to the parent page?

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to pass a SESSION variable from am embedded IFRAME to the parent page?

Meaning:

```
<form>

<iframe>
upload image to fake AJAX.
With PHP, set $_SESSION to be the location of the temporary uploaded photo
</iframe>

<input type="submit" />  // will this form submit have the $_SESSION variable set from the IFRAME?

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP sessions are, by default, implemented using cookies (which are per-domain).

You don't need to do anything explicit to share them between different frames (except keep them on the same domain).

Comment: So, what you're saying is that this will work. Is there any Security concerns I should be aware of?

Comment: Nothing beyond the usual ones.